# need guidance for creating a calendar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I have to use a calendar in my iPhone application. I tried hard, but could not find any inbuilt API in iPhone SDK for this purpose. Now I am going to create calendar by myself and need some guidance for it.

I have created 5 rows of 7 buttons (i.e, 35 buttons in all) and will be using it as the date, and then later I will add other graphics for the days and month. I have taken these buttons in an array and will be adding/changing their properties in a loop.

I am having a doubt if this is correct approach or if some one could suggest a better approach to me.

```
btnCal29=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22.0f, 312.0f, 35.0f, 35.0f)];
btnCal30=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(62.0f, 312.0f, 35.0f, 35.0f)];
btnCal31=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(102.0f, 192.0f, 35.0f, 35.0f)];
btnCal32=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(142.0f, 192.0f, 35.0f, 35.0f)];
btnCal33=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(182.0f, 192.0f, 35.0f, 35.0f)];
btnCal34=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(222.0f, 192.0f, 35.0f, 35.0f)];
btnCal35=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(262.0f, 192.0f, 35.0f, 35.0f)];

arrCalendarbutton = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:btnCal1,btnCal2,btnCal3,btnCal4,btnCal5,btnCal6,btnCal7,btnCal8,btnCal9,btnCal10,btnCal11,btnCal12,btnCal13,btnCal14,nil];

for(int i = 0; i<[arrCalendarbutton count];i++)
{
    [(UIButton *)[arrCalendarbutton objectAtIndex:i] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [(UIButton *)[arrCalendarbutton objectAtIndex:i] addTarget:self action:@selector(cal) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [(UIButton *)[arrCalendarbutton objectAtIndex:i] setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[(UIButton *)[arrCalendarbutton objectAtIndex:i] setTitle:@"11" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview: (UIButton *)[arrCalendarbutton objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

I am using above code to show the buttons(not added code for all buttons here). I will of course be changing the title of the buttons on later changes but for now I am only focusing on design.

Am I going in the right direction? Is there a better way?

Comment: There is also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634000/calendar-in-iphone-app) to a similar question.

Comment: Oh my repetition.  That list can be implemented programmatically using loops and collections (if you don't go for the library option suggested).

Comment: i found my calendar as kal calender here, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you'll find these links helpful

- [Kal](http://github.com/klazuka/Kal)
- [GCCalendar](http://github.com/guicocoa/GCCalendar)

I wouldn't connect every button to a named variable.

do soemthing like this:

```
NSMuteableArray *array = [[NSMUteableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0; i<31; i++){
    UIButton *b = ....;
    //customize b
    [array addObject:b];
    [b release];
}
```

If you are iterating over an array, for-each is recommended 
instead of

```
for(int i = 0; i<[arrCalendarbutton count];i++)
```

do

```
for(UIButton *b in arrCalendarbutton)
```

Comment: Definitely don't reinvent the wheel.  Just take Kal, or Tapku Lubrary, or GCCalendar and supply them the datasource and youre done. Those guys (particularly the first two I mentioned) have spent years to make their implementations look beautiful and function quickly. Besides those, however, there really isn't much more out there that's open source. I've been looking. I recreated Kal to go with the iPad's layout, but it's still nothing like iCal.